Route planning based on a floorplan
I am happy to use any input data format that the software might require. Given a floor-plan and start/end points, the software should automatically provide the shortest route. Bonus if it allow waypoints, but not really necessary.
Gratis, preferably FOSS, and I don't care which o/s or browser is required. This will be difficult enough to find, that I will have to accommodate it.

A lot of game engines have path finding algorithms for in game characters and pathfinding AI logic. They don't work on floorplans though, as far as I've seen, and require some sort of node based path network, typically a navigation mesh for 3D games, or some tile map for 2D games. Could you get one of those data structures instead of a plan? Or alternatively would be willing to generate one by, says, processing said plan to obtain key nodes?

Wow! Lateral thinking. I like this idea, and will look into it. Thanks

What is your goal? Visualizing it? Getting coordinates? Drawing paths? Godot probably could do that, though I never played with it. Otherwise Blender can get shortest paths https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/273207/shortest-edge-paths-between-two-empties

Thanks. I am thinking "how to get there" in maps in airports, shopping malls, government buildings, universtities, etc. Possibly evacuation routes. Just routing in general on indoor maps
